# Best way to update a large number of dynamodb items from a list

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, multiprocessing, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a python list of approximately 500,000 strings, each element in the list corresponds to an id for a item in the dynamodb table I want to update.

My question is, what would be the best way of iterating through this list and performing the same update query on each item?

I have tried to use

```
data = pd.read_csv(filename)
pool = Pool(50)
results = pool.imap_unordered(job, data['item_id'].astype(str).tolist())
```

where 'job' is the following method:

```
def job(item_id):
    dynamodb = boto3.resource(
        'dynamodb',
        aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
        aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
        aws_session_token=aws_session_token,
        region_name=region
    )
    table = dynamodb.Table('my-table')
    response = table.update_item(
        Key={
            "id": item_id
        },
        UpdateExpression="set x=:new",
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':new': []
        },
        ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
    )
```

However, while the script executes without error, the changes do not persist in the dynamodb table and I feel as though I am misunderstanding how to use a pool of processes on a boto3 resource in order to make this task somewhat efficient over 500,000 items.

It's also worth noting that when i print out the response received I am getting HTTP 200 responses.

Comment: Batch writer is for putting an entire record rather than updating a single attribute in a record right? I'm trying to set a nested attribute 'price' to an empty list, effectively clearing this attribute for the 500k records. I used update_item because I want to only update the one attribute

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the DynamoDB documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes):

> DynamoDB does not support empty sets.

So you cannot assign an empty set value (I'm surprised the operation didn't return an error...). Rather, you should use the `remove` operation of `UpdateItem` to remove the entire set attribute.

Comment: I don't think there is an issue with updating an existing array item in a record with an empty array, i am able to do this when updating a single record.

Also, one of the requirements of the task I am completing is that the attribute is not removed. 

The issue appears to happen when I am attempting to perform the task on an array of 500k items using a pool.